# Knowing if a Scala object is an instance of Case Class

Tags: scala, typing

I was wondering if there as a way to know if an object is an instance of a case class. I was trying to find some structural type matching `unapply`, I notice they inherit `Product`. My real need for a function that would go something like:

```
def withCaseClass[T <: /* matcher for case class */](obj:T) ...
```

My major interest is to make sure only case classes can be passed to this function.

Comment: who's trying to pass non-case classes to it? terrorists?

Comment: I wanted to limit at compile time that only object that have than can be used in a switch are being passed to the method.

Comment: How do you want to use them in pattern matching (Scala doesn't have a switch construct, although a switch can be expressed using pattern matching - pattern matching is more general)?

Answer (score 7):

A `case class` is an implementation detail. One can create a class that acts exactly like a case class -- and the ability to do so is a very important thing, as it ensures one *can* switch to a normal class if some particular requirement makes that a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

There's no marker trait for either case classes or tuples, so I'm afraid your best bet might be to check that it extends Product and isn't in any package starting with "scala.*". :/

Answer (score 2):

As you can do exactly the same "manually" what the compiler does for case classes, and because the produced byte-code would be indistinguishable (is this even a word? looks funny...), you are out of luck. The real question is: Why should you care about?

Answer (score 0):

In Java I've used

```
Product.class.isAssignableFrom(someClassThatMayBeACaseClass);
```

to detect if something is a case class.  Though it's likely there are Products that are not case classes.